# MySQL count across multiple tables with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I need to generate a report of how many registered users there are based on groups with more than 'x' members (members are users and can be registered or not registered).

A real simplified version would be:

```
table.users
userid int(11) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY (userid)

table.groups
gid int(11) NOT NULL,
guserid int(11) NOT NULL,
groupid VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (gid)
```

And some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO users (userid, username) VALUES
('1','bob'),('2','steve'),('3',''),('4','jill'),
('5',''),('6',''),('7','john'),('8','stan'),
('9',''),('10','rachel'),('11','lisa');
```

Out of those 11 users, 7 have usernames (registered)

```
INSERT INTO groups (gid, guserid, groupid) VALUES
('1','1','ABC123'),('2','2','ABC123'),('3','3','XYZ789'),('4','4','ABC123'), 
('5','5','XYZ789'),('6','6','ABC123'),('7','7','DEF456'),('8','8','ABC123'), 
('9','9','DEF456'),('10','10','XYZ789'),('11','11','XYZ789');
```

I need to get the groupid, the count of that groupid in the groups table, and then the count of the users registered for that group (username is not null).

```
'ABC123','5','4'
'XYZ789','4','2'
'DEF456','2','1'
```

The real data is a much larger subset and I need to get only results where we have a possible number of users in groups of more than 500 (which is around 1,000 groups which have anywhere from 500 to 25000 possible members).  Everything I've tried involves nested selects and I can get close, but not the exact data returned that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `LEFT JOIN` to the `users` table and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT groupid, COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT u.username)
FROM groups AS g
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userid = g.guserid AND u.username <> ''
GROUP BY groupid
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b65d59/1)

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT groups.gid,
       COUNT(groups.gid),
       SUM(CASE WHEN users.username='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM groups
  JOIN users ON users.userid=groups.guserid
 GROUP BY groups.gid
```

Untested.

Comment: I like the SUM(CASE WHEN - I hadn't thought of that and I'm able to dig a lot more useful info out of this report using that on other fields.  Thanks!